# Does this linear system have a unique solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

$x \in R^n$, $P \in R^{n \times n}$, $P$ is a known stochastic matrix (each row sums to 1), $b \in R^{n}$ is a known non-zero vector. $e = [1, \dots, 1]^T \in R^n$, we have the linear system:

$x = P^Tx + b$

$e^Tx=0$

Does this linear system have a unique solution?

Added:
Assuming we already know one solution for this linear system, is this a unique solution?

Comment: If $P$ is the identity matrix, the first equation has no solution for nonzero $b$.

Comment: @saulspatz What if we assume there is at least one solution?